# Draw an electrical machine

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following figure on Tikz:

[image]

I have tried with this code, but the lines are distorced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.6,xscale=0.6]
\def\n{24} 
\def\nst{6}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw[black, line width=1mm] (0,0) circle (5);
\draw[line width=0.3mm] (0,0) circle (1);


\draw (7.5,0) node [anchor=east][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$A_Z = 0$};

\foreach \angle in {1,...,\n}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\compute{\angle*360/\n}
\begin{scope}[rotate around={\compute:(O)}]

\draw (3.5,0) -- ++(0:0.5)  arc (0:7.5:3.5) -- ++(7.5:-0.5) arc (0:7.5:3);

\draw (4,0) arc (0:7.5:4);

\end{scope}
}

\foreach \angle in {1,...,\nst}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\compute{\angle*360/\nst}
\begin{scope}[rotate around={\compute:(O)}]

\draw (2,0) -- ++ (0:0.3) arc (0:-10:2) -- ++ (0:0.5);
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anybody can give me some tips and help me?

Comment: Please upvote and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Try adding `cm` to the radius in arc.

Comment: I tried, but did not result :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a possibility. All is pretty straightforward except for the blue lines. For them I used the `calc` library to previously compute some coordinates (rotating a `scope`).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,thick,rotate=30]
  \draw[line width=1mm,fill=gray!15] (0,0) circle (5);
  \draw[red,fill=white] (-1.5:4) foreach\i in {0,10,...,350} {arc (\i-1.5:\i+1.5:4) -- (\i+1.5:3.5) arc (\i+1.5:\i+8.5:3.5) -- (\i+8.5:4)};
  \foreach\i in {1,2,...,6}
  {
    \begin{scope}[rotate=60*\i-60]
      \coordinate (A\i) at (-10:2.5);
      \coordinate (B\i) at ($(A\i)+(0.4,0)$);
      \coordinate (C\i) at ($(A\i)+(0.4,-0.2)$);
      \coordinate (D\i) at ($(A\i)+(0.6,-0.2)$);
      \coordinate (H\i) at (10:2.5);
      \coordinate (G\i) at ($(H\i)+(0.4,0)$);
      \coordinate (F\i) at ($(H\i)+(0.4,0.2)$);
      \coordinate (E\i) at ($(H\i)+(0.6,0.2)$);
    \end{scope}
  }
  \draw[blue,fill=blue!20] (A1) \foreach\i in {1,...,6}
     {-- (B\i) -- (C\i) -- (D\i) to[out=60*\i+10,in=60*\i+230]
         (E\i) -- (F\i) -- (G\i) -- (H\i) arc (60*\i-50:60*\i-10:2.5)};
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the picture:
[image]

**Edit 1:** And these are the coordinates I'm using.
[image]

**Edit 2:** A little bit explanation of some syntax. Let's take a look at the line

```
\draw[red,fill=white] (-1.5:4) foreach\i in {0,10,...,350} {arc (\i-1.5:\i+1.5:4) ...};
```

This will draw a complex path starting at the point `(-1.5:4)`, that is, a point which polar coordinates are radius 4 (4 cm from the origin) and angle -1.5 (1.5 degrees from the x-axis, clockwise). Then it will repeat the code inside the curly brackets six times, substituting `\i` for the values `0,60,120,180,240,300`. For example, the first iteration will be for `\i=0`, so

```
\draw[red,fill=white] (-1.5:4) arc (0-1.5:0+1.5:4) ...;
```

So the first part of the complex path will be an `arc` starting at the point `(-1.5:4)` with an initial angle of -1.5 degrees, a final angle of 1.5 degrees and a radius of 4 cm. In this case all the angles are centered at the origin, but for more information about the center of the arcs this post could be helpful: [How is arc defined in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175016/how-is-arc-defined-in-tikz)

Comment: +1 very nice figure -- can you kindly educate on the arc syntax

Comment: Thanks @jsbibra!!! I made an edit with some explanations about the syntax.