How to make the intersection smoother and more natural
 \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

     \clip(0,0) circle (.709cm);
        \draw[thick](-.35,.35) circle (.5cm);
    \fill[black] (-.35,.35) circle(.08cm);
     \draw[thick](-.35,-.35) circle (.5cm);
    \fill[black] (-.35,-.35) circle(.08cm);
     \draw[thick](.35,.35) circle (.5cm);
    \fill[black] (.35,.35) circle(.08cm);
     \draw[thick](.35,-.35) circle (.5cm);
    \fill[black] (.35,-.35) circle(.08cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 


Sergei Golovan's answer also has the similar problem.


Instead of drawing four separate circles and clipping them, you can draw four connected arcs like in the following code:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick] (-0.7071,0) arc (-135:45:.5cm) --
               (0,0.7071) arc (135:315:.5cm) --
               (0.7071,0) arc (45:225:.5cm) --
               (0,-0.7071) arc (-45:135:.5cm) -- cycle;
  \fill[black] (-.35,.35) circle(.08cm);
  \fill[black] (-.35,-.35) circle(.08cm);
  \fill[black] (.35,.35) circle(.08cm);
  \fill[black] (.35,-.35) circle(.08cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The result is:


thank you very much! I don't know how to calculate the start and end angle of arc.

There's a question for that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175016/how-is-arc-defined-in-tikz

A great tutorial

You can use a simplest path: \draw[thick] (-0.7071,0) arc (-135:45:.5cm) arc (135:315:.5cm) arc (45:225:.5cm) arc (-45:135:.5cm) -- cycle;

it works, thanks
